# Sending data over HTTP using POST with Arduino

Tags: http-post, arduino-uno

Hi I am trying to send data collected from an series of sensors to a server using Arduino with a WiFi shield.

My code is
    void readdata()
      {
      char dataBuff [300];

```
   logfile.seek(pos);
   pos = logfile.position();
  while(logfile.available()){
    while(logfile.position() < logfile.size()){
      String dataBuff = logfile.readStringUntil('\n');
 Serial.println(F("DataBuff is"));
 Serial.println(dataBuff);

        //Variables for WiFi Shield
  char ssid[] = "xxx";       //your network SSID (name)
  char pass[] = "xxx"; 
  char server[] = "http://example.com";
  int dataSize = sizeof(dataBuff);

  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(F("Attempting to connect to SSID: "));
    Serial.println(ssid);

    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 1 second for connection:
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println(F("Connected to wifi"));
 // #endif

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println(F("WiFi shield not present"));
    // don't continue:
   while (true);
  }

  int fileSize = 0;
  fileSize = sizeof(dataBuff);
  uint32_t fileLength = 0;
  fileLength = 137 + fileSize + 40;
  Serial.println (fileLength);

  Serial.println(F("\nStarting connection to server..."));
  Serial.println(server);
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println(F("connected to server"));
    // Make a HTTP request:

  client.print(F("POST /uploadf HTTP/1.1\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Host: example.com\r\n"));
  client.print(F("User-Agent: Frank/1.0\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Accept: */*\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Connection: keep-alive\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Content-Length: "));
  client.print(fileLength);
  client.print(F("\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Content-Type: multipart/form-data;   boundary=710ff0c6cf2d4c73b12db64cab12e58c\r\n"));
  client.print(F("\r\n"));
  client.print(F("--710ff0c6cf2d4c73b12db64cab12e58c\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""));
  client.print(dataSent);
  client.print(F("\""));
  client.print(F("\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"));
  client.print(dataBuff);
  client.print(F("\r\n--710ff0c6cf2d4c73b12db64cab12e58c--\r\n"));
  }

  while(client.connected()){
    while (client.available()&& status==WL_CONNECTED) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }
  }

  client.stop();

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\n"));
    Serial.println(F("disconnecting from server."));
    client.flush();
    client.stop();

  } 
    }
   }
 logfile.close();
 while (true);
  }
```

When I run the code the data is read correctly but upon connecting to the server I get the following

connected to server

disconnecting from server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go this fixed:
For anyone who runs into similar problem the attached code allows you to open a file and read the data one line at a time and upload t a server.

```
 void readdata()
  {

            //Variables for WiFi Shield
  char ssid[] = "example";           //your network SSID (name)
  char pass[] = "example";           
  char server[] = "http://sleeppapi.pythonanywhere.com";

  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(F("Attempting to connect to SSID: "));
    Serial.println(ssid);

    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 1 second for connection:
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println(F("Connected to wifi"));
 // #endif

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println(F("WiFi shield not present"));
    // don't continue:
   while (true);
  }

  int fileLength = 0;
  fileLength = 137 + filesize + 40;
  Serial.println(filesize);

  Serial.println(F("\nStarting connection to server..."));
  Serial.println(server);
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println(F("connected to server"));

    // Make a HTTP request:

  client.print(F("POST /uploadf HTTP/1.1\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Host: example.com\r\n"));
  client.print(F("User-Agent: Frank/1.0\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Accept: */*\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Connection: keep-alive\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Content-Length: "));
  client.print(fileLength);
  client.print(F("\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Content-Type: multipart/form-data;     boundary=710ff0c6cf2d4c73b12db64cab12e58c\r\n"));
  client.print(F("\r\n"));
  client.print(F("--710ff0c6cf2d4c73b12db64cab12e58c\r\nContent-Disposition:  form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""));
  client.print(dataSent);
  client.print(F("\""));
  client.print(F("\r\n"));
  client.print(F("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"));
  logfile=SD.open(nameFile);
  while(logfile.available()){
    while(logfile.position() < logfile.size()){
      String dataBuff = logfile.readStringUntil('\n');
      client.print(dataBuff);
      client.print("\n");
    }
  }
  client.print(F("\r\n--710ff0c6cf2d4c73b12db64cab12e58c--\r\n"));
  //client.flush();
  }

  while(client.connected()){
    while (client.available()&& status==WL_CONNECTED) {
      char c = client.read();
     Serial.write(c);
   }
 }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\n"));
    Serial.println(F("disconnecting from server."));
    client.stop();

  } 
 logfile.close();
 while (true);
  }
```